# Multi site Active Directory fail over

Tags: active-directory

Let say I have two site, connect with WAN link.
Site A have 1 DC.
Site B have 1 DC.
In general case, the fail over is working if one of DC down. Client will use any available DC.

What if the WAN link down? Will each DC still provide services to each site?
If someone changed the Group policy / Add new user at one site when the WAN link down, will the change correctly replicate after WAN link resume?

Comment: Assuming everything is configured appropriately... Yes to all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all the domain controllers will synchronize changes when the connection comes back, and they can continue serving the site with all the roles installed on both servers. You'd only get problems if the link between domain controllers is down more than [the tombstone lifetime for the forest](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc784932(v=ws.10)).

> The tombstone lifetime in an Active Directory forest determines how
>   long a deleted object (called a “tombstone”) is retained in Active
>   Directory Domain Services (AD DS). The tombstone lifetime is
>   determined by the value of the `tombstoneLifetime` attribute on the
>   Directory Service object in the configuration directory partition.